# MySQL: Two Date Chooser Excepcion

Tags: java, mysql, date

I'm working on a program which requires two jDateChoosers to pick a date range. Since I want the date range to be "valid", I don't want the "before" date to be after the "after" date (so if the max date is 10/15, the min date can't be 10/16), nor visaversa. So I used some Listeners to limit the viable date ranges for each in accordance to each other.

```
until_date.getJCalendar().setMaxSelectableDate(new Date());
    until_date.getDateEditor().addPropertyChangeListener((PropertyChangeEvent e) -> {
        try {
            since_date.setMaxSelectableDate(until_date.getDate());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    });
    since_date.getDateEditor().addPropertyChangeListener((PropertyChangeEvent e) -> {
        try {
            until_date.setMinSelectableDate(since_date.getDate());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    });
```

However, I'm getting an `IllegalStateException: Attempt to mutate in modification` every time I actually pick a date on any of the choosers. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL?

Comment: my mistake, sorry. But it's not too far: I will use those dates later to build an MySQL query.